# Any linear combination of $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$ is also separable over $K$

Tags: linear-algebra, extension-field, separable-spaces

Let $E$ be a finite extension over $K$. If $E = K(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ and each $a_i$ is separable over $K$ then can we say that any linear combination of $\{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n\}$ is also separable over $K$?

Answer (score 0):

The set of separable elements over a field form a field in itself, and in particular linear combinations. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511542/separable-closure-is-a-field).